# How would I replicate python rfind and string multiplication in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, string, find

I have this python code that I want to replicate in Javascript but I have no clue how I would do the Python's rfind or find methods. As well as the python string multiplication. For example:

```py
' ' * 5 + '^' * 7
```

Anything helps, thank you!

Comment: So you need 5 spaces and 7 carets?

Comment: Try this: `" ".repeat(5) + "^".repeat(7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rfind

```
txt = "Mi casa, su casa." // both languages

x = txt.rfind("casa") //python

x = txt.lastIndexOf("casa") //js
```

find

```
txt = "Hello, welcome to my world." // both

x = txt.find("welcome") // pyhton

x = txt.indexOf("welcome") // js
```

replicate

```
' ' * 5 + '^' * 7 // python
" ".repeat(5) + "^".repeat(7) // js
```